# How to adjust the following ggplot2 graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I conduct a research about global education recently and the following graph is an important plot of my research.

[image: motivation-performance of education]

```
ggplot(sam_data,aes(JOY,PV)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = Individualism))+
  facet_grid(occupation~as.factor(Gender)) + 
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2.0,"cm"),legend.text = element_text(size = 5,face = "plain")) + 
  scale_color_continuous("Individualism",labels=sam_data$country,breaks =sam_data$Individualism)+
  geom_smooth()
```

And the problem is obvious :

1) The correlation line of different countries is all combined into one line, instead of different lines when segmented into gender and occupation.

2) The legend is a mess as I want to make it shown clear the countries corresponding to their individualism level. However, I tried to adjust many parameters of the legend and it did not work so much.

3) Also, I do not know how to delete the white gap produced by the `breaks` parameter. Any thoughts would be great!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example dataset.

Comment: I am really sorry@ycw, because the paper has not been published, data could not be shared as required by my boss, I know it would be hard for you to offer help, so any ideas or hints would be helpful. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: A small subset of your data would be helpful. Sometimes people even create some fake data as examples just to represent the characteristic and nature of the data. No need to feel sorry. I just want to increase the chance for you to get useful feedback.

Comment: Thanks @ycw, I would try to provide some reproducible date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the second problem by adjusting the `aes` parameter in `ggplot` function. The new code of mine is as follows

```
ggplot(sam_data,aes(JOYSCIE,PV1SCIE,group = CNTRYID)) + 
geom_point(aes(color = Individualism.comp4))+
facet_grid(recode.OCOD3~as.factor(Gender0women1men)) + 
theme(legend.key.height = unit(3.0,"cm"),legend.text = element_text(size = 5,face = "plain"))  + 
scale_color_gradientn("Individualism",labels=sam_data$CNTRYID,breaks =sam_data$Individualism.comp4,colors = rainbow(4))+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2,2))
```